# How can i test if a web site in Azure is frozen?

Tags: azure, powershell

I am currently looking for the status of a site , but it says its up and running. But in fact the website has stopped responding.

Will the following work if the site is frozen :

```
$HTTP_Request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create('https://testsite.azurewebsites.net')
$HTTP_Response = $HTTP_Request.GetResponse()
$HTTP_Status = [int]$HTTP_Response.StatusCode
If ($HTTP_Status -eq 200) {
    Write-Host "Site is OK!"
} Else {
   Write-Host "The Site may be down, please check!"
}
If ($HTTP_Response -eq $null) 
{ 

} Else { 
   $HTTP_Response.Close() 
}
```

I have no site that is frozen so I cannot test this piece of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this [Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/?view=azps-10.0.0).

- While using your code.

[image]

- Created a sample [web site](https://i.imgur.com/2ZIsmHe.png) and [website2](https://i.imgur.com/Q1esewT.png).

```bash
$url = "https://yourwebapp.azurewebsites.net"
```

**Code:**

```bash
$url = "sampath12345.azurewebsites.net"

try {
    $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method Get -UseBasicParsing
    $status = $response.StatusCode

    Write-Host "URL: $url"
    Write-Host "Status Code: $status"
} catch {
    Write-Host "Failed to connect to the URL: $url"
    Write-Host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

- If the application is Stopped.

[image]

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I dont know exactly what your trying to say , will it work ?

Comment: yes  login with az login and use my code.

Comment: but from what i see you get status 200 in both., Is one meant to simulate a fozen/ non-responsive site ?

Comment: how does it give the fact that the site is frozen. could you please explain it. thanks

Comment: both are different apps prints of the application status.

Comment: different apps , ok. but what tells the user after they run your code that the site is non-responsive ?

Comment: what indicates to them it is frozen from the output ?

Comment: if application is frozen means application stop working it will 500 response.

Comment: but both of yours are working ?

Comment: so basically the status code should be 500 , right ?

Comment: some time Error: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. as well